# Adding fields to the Site model

Tags: django, django-models

I have an application that should serve various sites. The [Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/) is already there for that, but in this application some sites share certain assets (CSS, etc). Thus I would like to have an additional model (say `Asset`) with a One-to-Many relationship with `Site`.

I believe this essentially boils down to add a custom field to the `sites.models.Site` model. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Why should the field belong to the Site model? just add the field to the Asset and from Site you can access the reverse relation.

Comment: That would be the inverse relationship. I need a One-to-Many relationship from `Asset` to `Site`, i.e., the same asset can be used in different sites.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a foreign key to the `Site` model it [will be available](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) in the site instance automatically:

```
site.asset_set.all()
```

You can even provide the `related_name` to the [backward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for more readability:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name='assets')

...

site.assets.all()
```

Comment: That is the inverse relationship of what I pretend. However, this particular formulation returns this error: "core.Asset.site: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Site', which is either not installed, or is abstract.".

Comment: Current version of django doesn't enable the `Sites` framework by default.  You have to enable it by yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

Comment: Ok, I found the source of that error, the `django.contrib.sites` application was commented out in `settings.py`.